# Enabling a QPushButton when an item is selected in a QListView

Tags: qt

I basically got a QPushButton and a QListView connected to a QStandardItemModel.

The QPushButton allows to delete the selected items in the QListView. I'm trying to get the QPushButton only enabled if at least one item is selected in the QListView, but I can't find the correct signal for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right signal is [QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged). `QItemSelectionModel` object can be obtained using `view->selectionModel()`.

Answer (score 0):

clicked(QModleIndex) looks like it can be a decent starting point - if you setup a slot to receive that notification, you should be able to enable your button.

Using QtCreator/Designer:

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
  ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Without QtCreator, the connection would break down into something like this (Qt4 style):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent)
{
  QListWidget* listWidget = new QListWidget();

  // ... setup ui stuff, etc ...

  connect(listWidget, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), 
          this, SLOT(on_listWidget_clicked(QModelIndex));
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There are many ways to change selection. OP was talking about  deleting the selected items, your solution will not work in that case.

Comment: Yes, I agree that selectionChanged() is the approach that should be taken - I'm only answering the question regarding the enabling of a button.